# Why am i getting NetStream.Connect.Closed?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flashplayer-10, adobe-cirrus

When I execute the following:

```
private function setUpRecvStream():void {
                writeText("Connecting to: " + theirID);
                recvStream = new NetStream(netConnection, theirID);
                recvStream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStreamHandler);
                //play the recvStream
                recvStream.play("media");
                //attach the stream videoRecv
                videoRecv.attachNetStream(recvStream);
            }
```

Using a vaild string for `theirID` I'm getting the following:

```
Connecting to: 8640d30e760528b2c88662eacef67d693527e52549eb5e29fc405355a7db147e 

NetStream.Connect.Closed
```

I'm expecting `NetStream.Connect.Success` since I'm passing in a vaild string for `theirID`. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

Are you initializing your netConnection? Also, the stream you are connecting to might not be publishing "media".

The client you are connecting to must do sendStream.publish("media")

Answer (score 0):

before using this you need to connect to FMS

```
nc = new NetConnection();
nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusEvent);
nc.connect('rtmfp://stratus.adobe.com/cbd2224f9a56771b3d4d05c3-bd9b549abca2');

private function netStatusEvent(event:NetStatusEvent):void {
trace('NetConnection status event (1): ' + event.info.code);
    if (event.info.code == 'NetConnection.Connect.Success'){
    }
}
```